# Is this a virus? "{% comment %} {% endcomment %}"

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have not seen this before in my visual studio code. Does anyone know if this is a virus or not?

I believe I have only installed Live Server, Python, and the second live server option from the top.

Just recently my live server has not been showing up when I right-click a file, and now this is showing up when I "CTRL + K + C". Can someone please let me know if this is a virus?

Comment: That looks like comment from a template framework.

Comment: You probably changed a setting in VSCode to add a default template.

Comment: have you change the language ID to django-html

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I have solved this by completely deleting VS Code from my computer. I believe it is related to downloading a Django extension and could have been solved if I looked more closely into the settings of VS Code.